# select columns if a column has a value

Tags: select, mysql-5.6, if-not-exists

I have `RegiNum` and `EmpNum` columns in `users` table. If RegiNum column has a value it's considered as a student. If RegiNum is filled, I want to select Name and ID from that table. I used

```
select if(EmpNum is null,"",ID) as s_id from users where isActive=1;
```

This only returns IDs of students. How I can select the other fields too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of options here. One is to repeat the given structure for each column:

```
select
  if(EmpNum is null,"",ID) as s_id,
  if(EmpNum is null,"",Name) as s_name,
  .. etc
from users
where isActive=1;
```

This will return a row for every row in the table, showing empty strings for employees and values for students.

If the objective is to return only students a better solution is to put the filter in the WHERE clause:

```
select
  ID as s_id,
  Name as s_name,
  .. etc
from users
where isActive=1
and RegiNum is not null;  -- students only
```

With this approach fewer rows are sent from the DB to the application.

Comment: Both are working, I prefer 2nd method.

Comment: I'm glad it's working. This may just be a matter of word choice - but note that each will return a different list, so it's not just a matter of what you *prefer* but what the application *requires*.